# Dagger Construction Injection with Kotlin Class Delegation

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2, kotlin-delegate

I have the following Kotlin Class:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class SharedPrefClient 
    @Inject constructor(private val prefs: SharedPreferences) 
      : SharedPreferences by prefs {

   ...

}
```

In Dagger, I get the following error while building the project:

[image]

But it workes when I remove the class Delegation `: SharedPreferences by prefs`

Now my question is how can I use Dagger and Kotlin Class Delegation both together.

Comment: I'd like to try this for myself, so could you provide a _complete, minimal sample_? Also, what Dagger & Kotlin version are you using?

Comment: here is the simple project: https://github.com/Zoha131/dagger-kotlin-delegtion

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the problem is with `android.annotation.Nullable` which gets pulled into your code by using the `by` keyword, but which isn't accessible from outside the Android source code.

Usually you'd see the error directly if the type cannot be resolved, but in this case Kotlin generates Java code with the unknown annotation and Dagger tries processing that, leading to your error.

If you create your own interface other than `SharedPreferences` it will work just fine as you'd expect.

You might be able to add `android.annotation.Nullable` to your (compile only) classpath  somehow so that Dagger can do its thing, but it's probably easier to find another way.

---

I see three issues that you could raise here

- Dagger should fail better. The error message is of little help in this case
- Android shouldn't expose internal/hidden types,
- and/or Kotlin shouldn't pull in those hidden types

Comment: Currently, I have removed the class delegation and added functions manually. A little bit verbose but working for me.